# PL/SQL statement ignored, cannot display

Tags: oracle

I keep getting these problems when all I wanted was to display the maximum salary of an employee in a job id

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 6:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 8, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE
    lvc_jb_id VARCHAR2;
    lvn_max_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT max(salary), job_id
    INTO lvn_max_sal, lvc_jb_id
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    group by job_id
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MAX SALARY for job_id is'|| lvn_max_sal);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('job id '|| lvc_jb_id);
END;
```

Can anyone tell what I did wrong?

Comment: 1)Semicolon after `group by job_id` is missing 2) Length for the varchar2 variable has to be specified `lvc_jb_id VARCHAR2` -> `lvc_jb_id VARCHAR2(<<length>>)`

Comment: My new code generates a new problem, it says: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. Here's my new code:   `DECLARE`
    `lvc_jb_id VARCHAR2(50);`
    `lvn_max_sal NUMBER;`
`BEGIN`
    `SELECT max(salary), job_id`
    `INTO lvn_max_sal, lvc_jb_id`
    `FROM EMPLOYEES`
    `group by job_id;`
    `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MAX SALARY for job_id is'|| lvn_max_sal);`
    `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('job id '|| lvc_jb_id);`
`END;`

Answer (score 2):

Specify the size of the string.
eg: lvc_jb_id VARCHAR2(50);

End the select query with semicolon. Now it should work.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for a semicolon on my SELECT statement, I've done having no semicolon on my other codes and it worked...

Comment: I believe that the semicolon is required. :-)